# How to record webex presentation with video and audio?

Tags: webex

I'll take part in online presentation.

Can you give me advice what software use to record audio and video from [webex](http://www.webex.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Debut Video](http://www.nchsoftware.com/capture/index.html), but [Camtasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html) also does it. In fact, almost any screen capture software.

Comment: Thanks. This one http://www.nchsoftware.com/capture/index.html?

Comment: That is what I use. And it's a free trial (although I think limited to what file type to export - EG, you can only export to MPEG or AVI (I can't remember now).

Comment: Hm, i think Camtasia is suit for me. Can you tell me is there are any problems with sound configuration or anything else? In Camatasia or Debut.

Comment: You need to do your own research, but both will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

you will only be able to record if you are a Host. If not you have to use third party applications to record.